# when I build application to war SLO (single logout) stops working

Tags: tomcat, spring-security, tomcat7, cas, jasig

I am trying to implement CAS in spring based application. I have already configured CAS and connection to CAS from application and everything is working when I run application from jar. 
But when I try to build application to WAR package SLO (Single Logout) stops working. When I click log out I get logged out from application and from CAS but I'm still logged in other application.

Enviroment:

- Both WAR and CAS are deployed on local running tomcat 7, but as recommended in documentation I change localhost to my computer name.
- I'm using cas-server-webapp-3.5.2.1 and spring-boot-1.1.8.RELEASE
- I disabled HTTPS so all communication run on HTTP

This is my first attempt to integrate CAS so I have some doubts:
Can this be a problem:

```
2015-04-01 11:21:37,807 WARN [org.jasig.cas.util.HttpClient] - <Error Sending me
ssage to url endpoint [http://mycomputername:8080/App1/j_spring_cas_securi
ty_check].  Error is [Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://my
computername:8080/App1/j_spring_cas_security_check]>
```

- I've got the same message when running jars and there I'm properly log out from both applications
- Full log: http://pastebin.com/ShhgeNmN
- Log without info in application initialization: http://pastebin.com/DBW8fm1M

Also when I go to Tomcat Web Application Manager (mycomputername:8080/manager) and I expire sessions for second application I am properly log out from it, or rather I cannot access it anymore and I'm redirected to login in CAS.

@edit:
spring security: http://pastebin.com/K0BMVrLN

properties for App1 for War Deployment

```
app.service.security=http://mycomputername:8080/App1/j_spring_cas_security_check
app.service.home=http://mycomputername:8080/App1/
cas.service.login=http://mycomputername:8080/cas/login
cas.service.logout=http://mycomputername:8080/cas/logout
cas.url.prefix=http://mycomputername:8080/cas/
app.admin.userName=admin@cas.com
```

Comment: please update with your spring security context ....

Comment: added, not sure if you get notification after post edit

Comment: for single log out ,after calling `j_spring_security_logout` you should call `j_spring_cas_security_logout` and after that your Spring CAS Client Handle rest of log out process So don't delete `CAS TGT` ticket by yourself and for success log out URL enter `j_spring_cas_security_logout`

Comment: a helpful link:  http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.5.RELEASE/reference/cas.html

Comment: thanks for help, but I'm still logged in second application after log out, I think application have in cache session ID of users and doesn't invalidate it when CAS send notification because in CAS I can see "ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_DESTROYED"

Answer (score 1):

Logout Steps Using `Spring Security` And `CAS` :

1. The user requests /j_spring_security_logout (which set in `href` of logout button) which would log the user
   out of the local application and send the user to the logout success
   URL.
2. The logout success URL,that you should Set it
   `/j_spring_cas_security_logout`,  in order to logout out of all
   applications.
3. Then the user is redirected to the CAS single logout URL
   (`https://localhost:7443/cas/logout`).
4. On the CAS Server side, the CAS single logout URL then submits
   single logout requests to all the CAS Services. On the CAS Service
   side, JASIG's `SingleSignOutFilter` processes the logout request by
   invaliditing the original session.
5. At The end your `CASTGT` and `Jsession`(for Spring) destroyed and in
   app2 after request to any page you should redirect to CAS login page

Comment: Thanks. I know it should work this way, as i said I'm logged out from CAS so 1-3 steps are done, but somewhere on steps 4-5 is not right because my second application doesn't invalidate sessions. Also I noticed that if I invalidate session in tomcat manager second application redirects me to CAS as it should.
I believe tomcat either don't pass log out request to application, or stores some session information which it shouldn't. Because as I understand tomcat shouldn't have nothing to do with CAS.